# strutils.dcu not found in delphi 5

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 5.0 and i am getting error 'StrUtils.dcu not found' while compiling my project. Is this error related to the delphi version? I am not sure about in which version of Delphi StrUtils.pas added.  Thanks for help.

Comment: You do realise that Delphi 5 is 12 years old? (released 10th August 1999).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is related to the Delphi version - StrUtils was added in D6.  It has also changed between versions since then - newer versions have functions which previous versions do not.

Comment: I do believe that there are homebuild versions of StrUtils out there which are written for D5... google will probably find them for you.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly checked a delphi5 install disk, and didn't find strUtils.pas.